# Options for repairing iPod Touch with broken glass

Tags: ipod-touch, repair

I've got an 4th-gen iPod Touch with thoroughly smashed glass. What are my options for repair? It sounds like

1. Apple charges about $200
2. There are third-party repair-by-mail services that charge around $100, and
3. You can buy parts and do it yourself.

The first options seems a bit pricey for a $300 unit, and the third sounds too risky. That leaves the second option. I'm wondering if there is a reliable third-party service I can use, or if there are other options I've not considered?

Answer (score 3):

There's also the option of taking it to a local unofficial smartphone repair shop, which has the advantage of nobody having to pay for shipping. This is also risky though, since they might use low-quality parts and/or have poorly-trained staff, so it's probably only a decent option if you can find a convenient one with a good reputation.